# Persistant Oracle Connection/Queue based Insertion?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, oracle12c, c#-8.0

I am using custom api as database logger for auditlog. I need to use either persistent connection to database or queue based implementation (such that insertion is performed in bulk and other requests do not get disturbed and it must be threadsafe). Any ideas how I might achieve this?

**Database:** Oracle

**Logger Responsibility:** Only insertion

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Is there a reason not to use Oracle's built-in auditing? It's already designed to overcome these issues. Persistent connections are unsafe for security reasons (they can be hijacked), and any home-grown API is going to have performance issues and introduce latency to your application because it will add your auditing overhead to every audited transaction - there's really no way to avoid it. Oracle's auditing is robust, fine grained, and designed not to get in the way of what you're trying to do for the most part. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @pmdba , I do not need oracle's auditlogs. My application is related to financial domain so I need to audit custom data that app sends to servers and plus, I need to log request and responses of each api.